# Using NTwain - TransferError event is not raised for Paperjam and other errors in source

Tags: content-management-system, scanning, twain

We have built a custom application using NTwain to scan documents. When testing the application, we see that when an error is encountered on device side, like a paper jam, error handler event (TransferError) is raised for some scanners but it is not raised for some other scanners. Seeing this problem especially when using Canon model number, DR-G1130 and associated driver.

Driver UI has been disabled by setting ShowUI and CAP_INDICATORS to false in source's capabilities. We have looked at SourceDisabled event but it does not have any information regarding whether there was an error on device or not.
Please share if there is any setting or workaround recommended to overcome this.